# Why can't Alfred workflow get bash output?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, alfred

I was trying to make an Alfred workflow, using `Run Scipt`,`/bin/bash`.
Here is the script:

```
echo `python3 /Users/Ninzero/Documents/PythonProgramme/rav/rav.py choose`
```

I wanted to get the output and post a notification, but nothing appeared(I did remember to add the action of post notification). When I ran this command on terminal, it worked well.
[My workflow terminal imagine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJkEh.png)

Here is my python script

```
import sys
import random

if __name__ == "__main__":
    method = sys.argv[1]
    if method == "choose":
        with open('/Users/Ninzero/Desktop/a.txt','r') as files:
            alist = files.read().split('\n')
        choice = random.choice(alist)
        print(choice)
```

Comment: Do you intend for your script to write output to the console? If so, you don't necessarily need the echo before it

Comment: You don't need the echo; just run `python ... choose`.

Comment: Then what should i write in python script to let the {query} in the notification receive the result? print? @ClaytonWahlstrom

Comment: Does chepner's solution work?

Comment: @ClayWahlstrom Not really. I mean it works in terminal, bur the notification just can't show anything.

Comment: Please add your python script to the OP so we can see how you are using your data @Ninzero

Comment: Done @ClayWahlstrom

Comment: Is your script filter set to not require arguments like {query} such as in [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMIJ7N6ULXg&t=23)?

Comment: I asked on Alfred forum. The reason why is because Alfred don't know where is python3. Now it is solved. But thank you anyway. @ClayWahlstrom

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!